# Issue with matching random set of characters with the pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

As with given string, required to match the pattern with `RegExp()` containing

1. At least two UpperCase Characters
2. At least three digits in a given string

But the given patterns matches accordingly when the string is in sequence, rather than random

```
RegExp('[A-Z]{2,}', 'g'); // Eg: XXABXXX atleast two UpperCase Chararcters - returns true
RegExp('[a-z]{3,}', 'g'); // Eg: XX369XXX atleast three digits - returns true
```

Here is the below coding snippet showing that even when the above rules satisfies results to be false

```js
let str = "6Y0H5e3J4";

let upperCaseCharacters = new RegExp('[A-Z]{2,}', 'g');
let numberCharacters = new RegExp('[a-z]{3,}', 'g');

if(upperCaseCharacters.test(str) === false)
  console.log(str + ' Doesn\'t contain atleast two UpperCase Chararcters');
else
  console.log(str + ' Matches the pattern');

if(numberCharacters.test(str) === false)
 console.log(str + ' Doesn\'t contain atleast three digits');
else
 console.log(str + ' Matches the pattern');
```

As I'm looking for individual two specific pattern's for matching the above two rules

Comment: Literally speaking, `[A-Z]{2,}` means *at least two **sequential** chars between and including A to Z*. You are interpreting it the wrong way.

Comment: Also this `[a-z]{3,}` does not mean *at least three digits*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your patterns are checking for presence of allowed characters adjacent (next) to each other.

You may combine both conditions into single regex as:

```
/^(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:\D*\d){3})/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UvB2tY/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2})`: Positive lookahead to make sure that we have at least 2 uppercase characters ahead
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){3})`: Positive lookahead to make sure that we have at least 3 digits ahead

---

However if you want two separate patterns for both conditions then use:

```
// checks for 2 uppercase letters
upperCaseCharacters = /^(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}/
```

and

```
// checks for 2 digits
numberCharacters    = /^(?:\D*\d){3}/
```

Comment: `RegExp('^(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}', 'g');` and `RegExp('^(?:\D*\d){3}', 'g');` correct right? and may I know how I'm suppose to match for Special Characters having `!@#$%^&*-_=+\\|:;\',.\<>/?~` for atleast 3 characters. Have any idea about it..

Comment: No need to use `RegExp` constructor since regex is not using any variable. Just use `upperCaseCharacters = /^(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}/`. Now for special characters also use a 3rd pattern: `specialChars = /[-!@#$%^&*_=+\\|:;',.<>\/?~]/`

Comment: No need to use RegExp constructor since regex is not using any variable.. I didn't quite get you & does `g` Global contains with it and for specialChars 3 atleast how do we specify like `RegExp('[-!@#$%^&*_=+\\|:;',.<>\/?~]{3}', 'g');` is it correct?..

Comment: I humbly suggest you to do little bit of reading on using regex in Javascript. In JS `upperCaseCharacters = /^(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}/ ` is same as `upperCaseCharacters = new RegExp("^(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}") `. `g` is for global match but since you're just checking for presence better leave `g` out.  Finally to check presence of 3 special characters use: `specialChars = /^(?:.*[-!@#$%^&*_=+\\|:;',.<>\/?~]){3}/` as pattern

Comment: @anubhava, very nice code and thanks for sharing. Will this code be compatible only for javascript or any other languages too sir?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Thanks. this should work in any other regex engine like PHP, Perl, Python, Java as well.